# Interesting twist to the classic Twin Astronaut paradox: the astronaut twin moves against Earth's orbit and waits hovering in space

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

The scenario is simple.  The astronaut twin takes off, and travels at 67,000 mph (0.0001c) relative to the Earth, in a direction directly "backwards" along the earth's orbital path.  She then hovers in place, using rocket thrusters to prevent her from falling towards the sun. Her velocity with respect to the sun and the "fixed" stars is zero. 1 year later, the Earth comes around and she rejoins her brother by powering her thrusters to acheive the same velocity as the Earth.

The astronaut twin says that she will be older than her brother on Earth, because the Earth moved from her at 0.0001c.  She says her brother's clock will lose 0.16 seconds based on 1 year * $\sqrt{1-.0001^2}$.  The brother says no, you will be younger by that 0.16 seconds because he was still and his sister was moving at 0.0001c.    (Aside:  the impact of the lower gravity being so far from Earth works out to just 0.02 seconds, which both twins agree is extra aging for the sister.  The 0.16 seconds they disagree on has only to do with velocity.)

The sister argues further that she was the still one.  Ask the sun and the stars.  The brother responds "But you are the one who accelerated!  That makes you the one with the slow clock."

We start to agree with the brother, but then the sister floors us:  Well, let's say that we started both hovering in space side by side, still with respect to the sun and stars.  Then you lasso'd the Earth as it went by, and traveled around the sun on it.  By your reasoning, your clock would now be 0.16 seconds slow compared to mine because you accelerated.  *But it would then be 0.32 seconds slow compared to the Earth's*! How could your clock be running at a different speed than one that is in your same reference frame? Hah!

The poor brother is forced to admit, that does present a problem to his theory that who accelerates is important.

Can you help the brother out?  (Hint:  I think not.)

Comment: What did you get when you computed the proper time along both paths?

Comment: You are asking people to do the calculations for your example problem. You would get better responses and more responses, if you actually tried to do the calculation and ask people to point out where you have gone wrong. Otherwise, people are just going to downvote your question. I have not downvoted, but most people will

Comment: The short answer to your question is that in this example, both special relativistic time dilation effects and gravitational time dilation effects are in play. Which twin will be younger will depend on which effect has a greater magnitude than the other. Which will depend non -trivially on how far away from the earth did the space twin hover. Which can be figured out only by doing the calculations involved

Comment: There are _no_ interesting twists to the "Twin Paradox".  It has all been done many thousands of times across the world.  It is only an "interesting twist", if you are new to SR

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, the computation from the sister's viewpoint is easy, because in her frame the brother moved at a constant speed throughout.

The computations from the brother's viewpoint is harder, because, at the moment of reunification, he says that both his and his sister's clocks were running slow, by amounts that differed from each other and that kept changing during the course of the journey.  It is instructive to go ahead and carry out this somewhat more complicated calculation and check that it comes out to match what the sister says, but of course you know in advance that it has to turn out that way.

(It's considerably less instructive to ask other people to make that calculation.)